# How to make only one column of a table clickable

Tags: cell, clickable

I am trying to make a table cell clickable so that I can extract the cell value (member ID)and submit it to the server then re-direct the user to a new page displaying that member's profile data. I have used the following code to delegate the cells of the table as clickable, but it makes all cells clickable and I only want the first column of cells to be clickable.

The cell data for the ID is:

```
<td align="center" class="member_id" id="member_id" >
   <?php echo $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $table_name.`last_name` ASC ", 0, $cur_row); ?>
</td> <!--- ID --->
```

The JS file is:

```
$jq("#mem_dir").delegate("td", "click", function() {
   alert("Clicked on a cell");
   if ($jq(this).hasClass("member_id")) {
      alert("Clicked on a member ID");
   var member_id = $jq(this).text();
   alert ("Member ID is: " + member_id);
}
```

I would really like to do what I did for the email address cell data, but have not figured out how to do that.

Clickable email cell data:

```
<td><?php echo make_clickable($wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY $table_name.`last_name` ASC ", 3, $cur_row)); ?></td> <!--- email --->
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was far simpler than I had thought. I simply changed the selector of the delegate method to be the class of the column of interest:

```
$jq("#mem_dir").delegate(".member_id", "click", function() {
    var member_id = $jq(this).text();
    var member_id = member_id.trim();
    alert ("ID is: " + member_id);
```

With a little CSS on the class to create a pointer when hovering over the cell all worked fine:

```
#member_id {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```